# Add button to favorites page within my app. WP 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I have a panorama sound app with buttons that play sounds. How can I use a Hold event to allow user to save their favorite sound buttons to the Favorites page? I can do the Hold event but have no clue where to go from there as far as saving/copying the button as well as no clue how to handle isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

For Isolated storage look at these to links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090(v=vs.105).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx

And for the hold event you can look at this question:
[Hold Event Longlistselector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897492/hold-event-longlistselector)